# I freed everything but memory is leaking

Tags: c, valgrind, free

According to valgrind, this function, which is basically initializing a struct, is the leaking source:

```
Item* InitializeItem(char* name, int reg, char* adress)
{
    Item* i = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));

    int a = strlen(name) + 1;
    int b = strlen(adress) + 1;

    i->name = (char*)malloc(a*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(i->name, name);

    i->reg = reg;

    i->adress = (char*)malloc(b*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(i->adress, adress);

    return i;
}
```

Here is the free function:

```
List* Free_List(List* list)
{
    Node* new;
    new = list->First;

    while (new != NULL)
    {
        Node* aux = new->prox;
        free(new->item->name);
        free(new->item->adress);
        free(new->item);
        free(new);
        new = aux;
    }

    free(list);
}
```

I tried everything, but i don't understand what's happening. I apparently freed everything.
These are the two leaking errors i receive when i run valgrind with --leak-check=full:

```
41 (24 direct, 17 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
43 (24 direct, 19 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
```

Here is the Item structure:

```
typedef struct item Item;

struct item
{
    char *name;
    int reg;
    char *adress;
};
```

Here are the List and Node structures:

```
typedef struct list List;
struct list
{
    Node* node;
    Node *First, *Last;
};

typedef struct node Node;]
struct node
{
    Item* item;
    Node* prox;
};
```

And here, Initialize, Insert and Remove functions. I think they might have something to do with the error:

```
List*
InitializeList()
{
    List* list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));

    list->First = list->Last = NULL;

    return list;
}

void
Insert(Item* student, List* list)
{
    Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->prox = NULL;
    if (list->Last == NULL)
        list->First = list->Last = new;

    else
    {
        list->Last->prox = new;
        list->Last = list->Last->prox;
    }

    new->item = student;
}

Item*
Remove(List* list, int reg)
{
    Item* i = NULL;
    Node* ant = NULL;
    Node* seg = list->First;

    while (seg != NULL && seg->item->reg != reg)
    {
        ant = seg;
        seg = seg->prox;
    }

    if (seg == NULL)
    {
        i = NULL;
        return i;
    }

    if (seg == list->First && seg == list->Last)
    {
        i = seg->item;
        list->First = list->Last = NULL;
        free(seg);

        return i;
    }

    if (seg == list->Last)
    {
        i = seg->item;
        list->Last = ant;
        ant->prox = NULL;
        free(seg);

        return i;
    }

    if (seg == list->First)
    {
        i = seg->item;
        list->First = seg->prox;
        free(seg);
        return i;
    }

    else
    {
        i = seg->item;
        ant->prox = seg->prox;
        free(seg);
        return i;
    }

    free(seg);
}
```

And these are the final lines of the main function. Where the function Remove is called for the first time:

```
Item* ret = Remove(list, 123);
ret = Remove(list, 34);
list = Free_List(list);
```

Comment: Does it not show you where the blocks were allocated?

Comment: It does and i wrote that in the question. It's in the InitializeItem function. There's a line like this: by 0x400B9C: InitializeItem. I simply showed you part of the error message.

Comment: The definition of the Item structure may provide  clue

Comment: This is an ADT. The main function is just function calls. Also, i did not wrote the main function. My code is supposed to run without changing it.

Comment: It looks like you have modified your list inbetween, and lost track of one of the nodes. We would need to see more code to help.

Comment: ok, InitializeItem looks fine to me. The way Free_List traverses the list may be different from the way the nodes are allocated in the list and it may not be freeing a couple of nodes

Comment: This code looks fine for me. Maybe the source of the error is somewhere else where you work on the list

Comment: Could you post the code that calls InitializeItem and puts the return value into the list? As Johannes Walcher pointed out, there is probably a problem keeping track of the nodes.

Comment: You've neither shown nor (of necessity) used a `Free_Item()` function, even though `Free_List()` frees items.  So, when you `Remove()` an item from a list, you have no way to dispose of the Item that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

in this line in your `insert` method:

```
list->Last = list->Last->prox;
```

you lose track of what was previously in list->Last; you replace its value with the new allocated pointer; so the item that was previously at the last position will never be freed --> memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't free removed items from the list (at least based on what you've asked in your question). In the main function after you remove one item from the list you free the whole list which of course frees everything in the list but the item which has been removed from it.

Add another function like this for items out of the list:

```
void FreeItem(Item *it){
    free(it->name);
    free(it->adress);
    free(it);
}
```

I tested your code like bellow and there was no memory leaks:

```
Item* ret = Remove(list, 123);
ret = Remove(list, 34);
list = Free_List(list);

FreeItem(ret);
```